# Integrating over a fundamental domain in $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ under $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ action and the choice of the fundamental domain

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, homogeneous-spaces, haar-measure

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a fundamental domain in $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ under $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ action. It is well known that there exists a unique $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$-invariant probability measure on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ (also called Haar measure).

Choose a Haar measure $\mu$ on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and (the induced) Haar measure $\tilde{\mu}$ on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ so that
$$\mu(\mathcal{F})= \tilde{\mu}(\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z))=1.$$

The choice of the fundamental domain $\mathcal{F}$ is not unique, but I wonder how much it could affect the integration. Suppose I choose two fundamental domains $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}'$ and they satisfy
$$\mu(\mathcal{F})=\mu(\mathcal{F}')= \tilde{\mu}(\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z))=1.$$

My question is

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$. Is it possible that $\int_\mathcal{F} f d\mu<\infty$ but $\int_\mathcal{F'} f d\mu=\infty$? or they must be both finite or infinite?

I couldn't think of a proof or counterexample for this. Partial solution with proofs for some special classes of functions will also be appreciated. I have been trying to prove this (both finite or both infinite) just using $f(g)=\|g\|^{\alpha}$ or $f(g)=\|g^{-1}\|^{\alpha}$. But even this is hard.

Comment: I think you're overthinking things. As an analogy, replace $\mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathbb{Z}$. Then one can take any interval of the form $[a,a + 1]$ as a fundamental domain for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, and for any given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a \neq b$, there are of course nonnegative measurable functions $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $\int_{a}^{a + 1} f(x) \, dx = \infty$ but $\int_{b}^{b + 1} f(x) \, dx < \infty$.

Comment: It will depend on your precise definition of a fundamental domain: you did not give one and there is no standard definition.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Actually I am also using the same analogy but still not fully convinced that such an example exists for $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ or fundamental domain contained in $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I admits that the term "fundamental domain" is kind of ambiguous and the fundamental domain of $\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)/\text{SL}(d,\mathbb Z)$ is hard to visualize. But let's follow the wikipedia definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_domain

Comment: @user506835 Yes, such examples exist for any pair of fundamental domains for $\mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{R}) / \mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{Z})$. I think you may be misunderstanding why we work with fundamental domains. Usually we only consider integration over fundamental domains for measurable functions $f : \mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ for which $f$ is right $\mathrm{SL}(d,\mathbb{Z})$-invariant. In this case, the integral of $f$ over a fundamental domain is independent of the choice of fundamental domain.